# Did Governor of Moscow train bears to serve Vodka?

Tags: history, russia

> The Governor of Moscow trained a large bear to serve pepper Vodka to' his guests. If anyone showed reluctance in accepting the drink, the bear would remove the guest's clothes, an article at a time."

- Source: [Food and beverage Underground](http://www.foodandbeverageunderground.com/history-of-vodka.html)

Other people say it was Peter the Great? Did this really happen?